# Get Request Url pattern specific information on Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana

I am have a webservice which services GET requests of the following pattern
/v1/stores?name=<>&lat=23&lng=232....
There a number of query parameters which the request can accept. Is it possible to get url specific information kibana through log stash on kibana.What I really want is a average number of requests for each pattern along with their max, min and avg response types.I would also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want something like this as part of your logstash.conf:

```
grok {
  // some pattern that extracts out the uri param (everything after ?) into a param field
}
kv {
  source => 'param'
  field_split => '&'
}
// you might also need to urldecode {} the parameters
```